# Sheet inaccessible to macro: Error 1004: Application/Object Defined Error

Tags: vba, excel

This is happening in several of my macros, but this is the one in from of me:

```
Private Sub resettool()
'''resets step 2 input and user input on MPP tabs

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Call showsheets 'makes all of these sheets .Visible = True

'clear data from lookups and data corrals
Sheets("Media by Copy Lookup").Range("b1",Range("b1").End(xlToRight).End(xlDown)).ClearContents
Sheets("Total Media Lookup").Range("d1",Range("d1").End(xlToRight).End(xlDown)).ClearContents
Sheets("Total Media Lookup").Range("b2:c100").ClearContents
Sheets("Media by Copy Data").Range("a1",Range("a1").End(xlToRight).End(xlDown)).ClearContents
'etc etc
End Sub
```

It continues with similar data-clearing lines for a while. This started happening when I took someone else's code and cleaned it by removing the .Select usages as people on here have suggested. It seems that the macro isn't able to access the sheets I'm referencing, because a line runs successfully if I step into the code, manually select the referenced sheet, and then hit go (but then of course I get the same error when I try to edit another sheet).

Any ideas why the macro wouldn't be able to access these sheets unless I explicitly activate/select them? The sheets are all visible, so that shouldn't be the problem.

P.S. I've seen the guide on using .Rows.Count).End(xlUp) instead of End(xlDown) to find the bottom of my data and will implement that soon, but this issue is occurring no matter how I define the range; it's about the sheet.

Comment: all the `Range()` inside the other `Range()` need to be allocated to the same parent sheet: `Sheets("Media by Copy Lookup").Range("b1",Sheets("Media by Copy Lookup").Range("b1")...`

Comment: Well that was simple. Thanks!

Comment: You can simplify this using `With Sheets("Media by Copy Lookup")` & `End With`

Comment: That would definitely keep me from having super long lines of code. Thanks!